# Cambiar el valor del select2 con JQuery

Tags: jquery, select2

**AYUDA**

Hola necesito saber como puedo cambiar el valor de un `.select2`.

Es decir cuando le doy en el botón editar me tienen que rellenar todos los campos relleno todos los campos menos el  `select2`

**QUE CUANDO LE DEE EN EDITAR ME AUTORRELLENE EL `.SELECT` CON LA OPCION QUE SE A GUARDADO**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CODIGO HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-6">Proveedor</label>
          <input id="id_proveedor" type="hidden">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <select class="form-control select2" id="nombre_proveedor"
                                                    style="width: 100%"></select> <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
```

**MI JQUERY**

```
function modificar_compra(id_compra) {
        combo_select2();
    $.ajax({
        url: baseurl + 'Compras/obtener_compra',
        type: "POST",
        data: {id_compra: id_compra},
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data)
        {
            $("#modal_form_compra").unbind();
            $('#modal_form_compra').modal('show')
            $("#div_imagen_subir").hide();
            $("#div_imagen").show();
            $('#boton_multiuso').attr("onclick", 'actualizar_compra(' + id_compra + ')');
            $('#msg_cabecera').html("EDITAR COMPRA #" + id_compra);
            $('#numero_compra').val(data[0]['numero_recibo']);
            $('#id_proveedor').val(data[0]['id_proveedor']);
            $('#monto_total').val(data[0]['monto_total']);
            $('#fecha_compra').val(data[0]['fecha']);
            var proveedor = data[0]['id_proveedor'];
            console.log(proveedor);
//            $('#nombre_proveedor').select2();
            $('#nombre_proveedor').val(proveedor).trigger('change.select2');
            $('#id_imagen_editar').attr("src", baseurl + 'dist/img/compras/' + data[0]['url_imagen']);
        }
    });
}
function  combo_select2() {
    $("#nombre_proveedor").select2({
        theme: "bootstrap",
        placeholder: "Buscar proveedor",
        allowClear: true,
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        ajax: {
            url: baseurl + 'Compras/obtener_proveedor',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: $.map(data, function (obj) {
                        return {
                            id: obj.id_proveedor,
                            text: obj.nombre_proveedor
                        };
                    })
                };
            },
            cache: true
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: hola, que función ejecutas primero combo_select2()  ó modificar_compra(id_compra) ?

Comment: en mi DOM el combo_select2()  ya que lo utilizo para guardar compra

Comment: Prueba si te funciona $("#nombre_proveedor").select2("destroy");

Comment: destroy? no es destruir el select2?

Comment: si, es como hacerle una limpieza antes de cargar la nueva información

Comment: en que parte iria?

Answer (score 0):

```
function  combo_select2() {
    $("#nombre_proveedor").select2("destroy");
    $("#nombre_proveedor").select2({
        theme: "bootstrap",
        placeholder: "Buscar proveedor",
        allowClear: true,
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        ajax: {
            url: baseurl + 'Compras/obtener_proveedor',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: $.map(data, function (obj) {
                        return {
                            id: obj.id_proveedor,
                            text: obj.nombre_proveedor
                        };
                    })
                };
            },
            cache: true
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The select2('destroy') method was called on an element that is not using Select2.,  eso me sale

Comment: El metodo select2('destroy') lo estas llamando cuando aun no creas el select2, puedes hacer una validacion primero para saber que esta contruido y en caso de que si, lo destruyes en caso de que no no ejecutas la linea del destroy, otra manera de saltarte esto es que en el onready corras un .select2() para asegurarte que cuando corras combo_select2() este creado el select2

Comment: Sería interesante que añadieras explicaciones a la respuesta para hacerla verdaderamente útil.

Answer (score 0):

Agrega `destroy` entre las propiedades del `select2`, esto es algo similar a declararlo como `$("#nombre_proveedor").select2("destroy")`, pero como este aun no esta inicializado tiende a soltar error, por donde es mejor dejarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
function  combo_select2() {
    $("#nombre_proveedor").select2({
        destroy: true,//primero destruye el anterior y después lo vuelve a cargar
        theme: "bootstrap",
        placeholder: "Buscar proveedor",
        allowClear: true,
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        ajax: {
            url: baseurl + 'Compras/obtener_proveedor',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: $.map(data, function (obj) {
                        return {
                            id: obj.id_proveedor,
                            text: obj.nombre_proveedor
                        };
                    })
                };
            },
            cache: true
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, copie el código, pero sigue sin traerme ni auto completarme el `.select2`

Comment: @JoelMoreF. el modal, lo cargas cada vez que se le da en editar? es decir que tu modal lo cargas desde alguna url

Comment: onclick="modificar_compra" y eso me levanta mi modal

Comment: @JoelMoreF. si comentas esta linea `$('#nombre_proveedor').val(proveedor).trigger('change.select2');` y quitando la propiedad `destroy:true,` el select2 carga correctamente?

Comment: si carga incluso puedo buscar y si me trae resultado

Comment: @JoelMoreF. esta linea `$('#nombre_proveedor').val(proveedor).trigger('change.select‌​2');` modificala por esto: `$('#nombre_proveedor').val(proveedor).change();`

Comment: nada :c solo me carga el `.select`